# Questions where code has too many issues to cover in a simple answer

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

I sometimes see questions like this one: [Function not returning proper value, looking for a value in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418165/function-not-returning-proper-value-looking-for-a-value-in-a-list), where the OP is asking about a specific incorrect outcome, but the code itself has too many fundamental issues to be explained in a simple answer (e.g. you almost have to write a whole chapter about logic and problem solving to get to the real problems).

Frequently, with questions like this, answers tend to be all over the place, or spot specific issues that are only a small part of the picture; but it's rare that a single answer covers it. Also, I've noticed that the OP tends to not understand most of the answers when questions like this are asked (which makes sense, given that they seem to be having fundamental issues with the problem solving thought process to begin with).

Is this type of question "too broad"? Is it perhaps even "opinion-based" in that most answers seem to be complete (and unique) rewrites of the code? Or is it a reasonable question to have on the site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> you almost have to write a whole chapter about logic and problem solving to get to the real problems

I think this fall into the category of too broad. Whenever there will be too many good answers that will solve the problems OP has, it's too broad. Whenever you have to write an answer too long to give a concise and definitive solution, is too broad.

This is included in the [MCVE help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

> Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem

Once OP do this, he would have to see the problems his code has and naturally fix it (or so we hope).